# MySQL: super slow SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that is taking almost 8 seconds to execute. I did an `EXPLAIN` on the query, but I don't know how to interpret the results. Can someone please help me troubleshoot this problem? Here are the results of the `EXPLAIN`:

```
===============================================================================================================================================================================================
| id | select_type        | table                 | type    | possible_keys        | key             | key_len | ref                                     | rows | Extra                       | 
===============================================================================================================================================================================================
| 1  | PRIMARY            | <derived2>            | ALL     | (NULL)               | (NULL)          | (NULL)  | (NULL)                                  | 669  | Using filesort              | 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2  | DERIVED            | Workflow              | const   | PRIMARY              | PRIMARY         | 4       |                                         | 1    | Using index                 | 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2  | DERIVED            | DataSource            | ref     | PRIMARY,WorkflowId   | WorkflowId      | 4       |                                         | 1546 | Using where                 | 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2  | DERIVED            | ReadyLog              | ALL     | DataSourceId         | (NULL)          | (NULL)  | (NULL)                                  | 9463 |                             | 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2  | DERIVED            | DataSourceActivityLog | eq_ref  | PRIMARY,DataSourceId | PRIMARY         | 4       | func                                    | 1    | Using where                 | 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2  | DERIVED            | User                  | eq_ref  | PRIMARY              | PRIMARY         | 4       | my_db.DataSourceActivityLog.UserId      | 1    |                             | 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 3  | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | DataSourceActivityLog | ref     | DataSourceId         | DataSourceId    | 4       | my_db.DataSource.Id                     | 1135 | Using where; Using filesort |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

If there is additional information you need from me, please let me know. Thanks.

**UPDATE 1: the ugly query:**

```
SELECT WrappedData.*
FROM   (SELECT DataSource.Id,
               DataSourceActivityLog.Description,
               DataSourceActivityLog.UserId,
               DataSource.Status    AS StatusCode,
               ( CASE
                   WHEN User.Name IS NULL THEN 'System'
                   ELSE User.Name
                 END )              AS `Username`,
               ReadyLog.`Timestamp` AS `Received`,
               DataSourceActivityLog.`Timestamp`
        FROM   DataSource
               LEFT JOIN DataSourceActivityLog AS ReadyLog
                 ON ( ( ReadyLog.DataSourceId = DataSource.Id
                        AND ReadyLog.Description = 'ready' )
                       OR ( ReadyLog.DataSourceId = DataSource.RootId
                            AND ReadyLog.Description = 'ready' ) ),
               DataSourceActivityLog
               LEFT JOIN USER
                 ON USER.Id = DataSourceActivityLog.UserId,
               Workflow
        WHERE  DataSource.Id IN ( 138, 139, 140, 141,
                                  142, 143, 144, 145,
                                  146, 147, 148, 149,
                                  150, 151, 152, 153,
                                  154, 155, 156, 157,
                                  158, 160, 162, 163,
                                  166, 167, 169, 170,
                                  171, 173, 174, 176,
                                  177, 179, 180, 182,
                                  183, 185, 186, 187,
                                  189, 190, 191, 193,
                                  194, 196, 197, 199,
                                  200, 201, 203, 204,
                                  207, 208, 209, 211,
                                  212, 214, 216, 217,
                                  219, 221, 222, 223,
                                  226, 227, 228, 231,
                                  232, 233, 235, 237,
                                  238, 242, 243, 240,
                                  245, 246, 248, 250,
                                  252, 253, 255, 256,
                                  258, 259, 261, 263,
                                  264, 266, 267, 271,
                                  269, 272, 276, 274,
                                  277, 280, 282, 284,
                                  279, 287, 285, 288,
                                  290, 291, 293, 298,
                                  301, 299, 303, 304,
                                  306, 309, 310, 311,
                                  315, 316, 318, 322,
                                  323, 325, 329, 330,
                                  331, 336, 339, 343,
                                  345, 346, 348, 351,
                                  352, 354, 356, 357,
                                  358, 360, 362, 364,
                                  367, 369, 370, 373,
                                  375, 376, 378, 381,
                                  382, 384, 386, 388,
                                  390, 391, 394, 395,
                                  397, 400, 402, 404,
                                  405, 408, 412, 413,
                                  414, 415, 420, 421,
                                  424, 425, 429, 430,
                                  433, 434, 438, 439,
                                  441, 442, 443, 445,
                                  446, 447, 449, 451,
                                  452, 453, 456, 457,
                                  458, 459, 462, 464,
                                  465, 466, 470, 473,
                                  474, 475, 477, 478,
                                  481, 482, 483, 485,
                                  487, 488, 489, 491,
                                  493, 494, 495, 497,
                                  498, 500, 501, 502,
                                  504, 505, 507, 508,
                                  509, 512, 513, 514,
                                  515, 516, 518, 519,
                                  520, 521, 522, 524,
                                  525, 526, 527, 529,
                                  530, 531, 532, 534,
                                  535, 536, 537, 539,
                                  540, 541, 542, 544,
                                  545, 546, 547, 549,
                                  550, 551, 552, 553,
                                  554, 556, 557, 559,
                                  560, 561, 562, 564,
                                  565, 566, 568, 569,
                                  570, 571, 572, 574,
                                  575, 576, 577, 579,
                                  580, 581, 582, 583,
                                  585, 586, 587, 588,
                                  590, 591, 592, 593,
                                  594, 596, 597, 598,
                                  599, 601, 602, 603,
                                  604, 606, 607, 608,
                                  609, 611, 612, 613,
                                  614, 616, 617, 618,
                                  620, 621, 622, 623,
                                  625, 626, 627, 628,
                                  629, 631, 632, 633,
                                  634, 636, 637, 638,
                                  639, 641, 642, 643,
                                  644, 646, 647, 648,
                                  649, 651, 652, 653,
                                  654, 656, 657, 658,
                                  659, 660, 662, 663,
                                  664, 665, 667, 668,
                                  669, 670, 671, 673,
                                  674, 675, 676, 678,
                                  679, 680, 682, 683,
                                  684, 686, 687, 688,
                                  689, 691, 692, 693,
                                  694, 697, 698, 699,
                                  702, 703, 704, 707,
                                  708, 709, 710, 712,
                                  713, 714, 717, 718,
                                  719, 720, 721, 724,
                                  725, 726, 728, 729,
                                  730, 734, 735, 736,
                                  738, 739, 740, 742,
                                  743, 744, 747, 748,
                                  749, 751, 752, 753,
                                  755, 756, 757, 759,
                                  760, 761, 763, 764,
                                  765, 767, 768, 769,
                                  771, 772, 773, 775,
                                  776, 777, 779, 780,
                                  781, 782, 784, 785,
                                  786, 788, 789, 790,
                                  791, 793, 794, 795,
                                  797, 798, 799, 800,
                                  802, 803, 804, 807,
                                  813, 814, 815, 816,
                                  818, 822, 823, 824,
                                  825, 830, 831, 832,
                                  834, 835, 836, 837,
                                  839, 840, 841, 842,
                                  844, 845, 846, 848,
                                  849, 850, 852, 853,
                                  855, 856, 858, 859,
                                  860, 862, 863, 864,
                                  866, 867, 868, 870,
                                  871, 872, 874, 875,
                                  876, 877, 879, 880,
                                  881, 883, 884, 886,
                                  888, 889, 891, 892,
                                  893, 895, 899, 900,
                                  902, 903, 905, 906,
                                  908, 909, 911, 912,
                                  914, 915, 917, 918,
                                  920, 921, 923, 925,
                                  927, 929, 931, 932,
                                  934, 936, 938, 940,
                                  942, 944, 946, 948,
                                  950, 952, 953, 955,
                                  956, 958, 959, 961,
                                  962, 963, 965, 966,
                                  968, 969, 971, 972,
                                  974, 975, 977, 978,
                                  979, 981, 982, 983,
                                  987, 988, 991, 992,
                                  994, 995, 996, 998,
                                  1000, 1001, 1002, 1003,
                                  1005, 1007, 1008, 1009,
                                  1011, 1013, 1014, 1016,
                                  1017, 1019, 1020, 1022,
                                  1023, 1024, 1025, 1028,
                                  1029, 1032, 1033, 1035,
                                  1036, 1038, 1040, 1041,
                                  1043, 1045, 1046, 1049,
                                  1050, 1052, 1053, 1055,
                                  1056, 1059, 1060, 1063,
                                  1064, 1067, 1068, 1070,
                                  1071, 1073, 1074, 1076,
                                  1077, 1079, 1080, 1082,
                                  1083, 1087, 1088, 1090,
                                  295, 296, 338, 1551,
                                  1552, 1554, 1556, 1559,
                                  1561, 1563, 1565, 1567,
                                  1568, 1570, 1572, 1574,
                                  1576, 1578, 1580, 1581,
                                  1583, 1585, 1587, 1589,
                                  1591, 1593, 1595, 1597,
                                  1599, 1601, 1603, 1605,
                                  1607, 1609, 1611, 1613,
                                  1614, 1617, 1618, 1621,
                                  1622, 1625, 1626, 1629,
                                  1630, 1634, 1638, 1639,
                                  1642, 1643, 1645, 1646,
                                  1651, 1652, 1657, 1658,
                                  1662, 1664, 1666, 1669,
                                  1672, 1676, 1674, 1677,
                                  1680, 1681, 1684, 1685,
                                  1689, 1690, 1694, 1698,
                                  1704, 1706, 1709, 1712, 1633 )
               AND DataSourceActivityLog.Id = (SELECT DataSourceActivityLog.Id
                                               FROM   DataSourceActivityLog
                                               WHERE  DataSourceActivityLog.DataSourceId = DataSource.Id
                                                      AND ( DataSourceActivityLog.Description = 'data_entry_ready' )
                                               ORDER  BY TIMESTAMP DESC
                                               LIMIT  1)
               AND ( DataSource.Status = '103' )
               AND Workflow.Id = 14
               AND DataSourceActivityLog.`DataSourceId` = DataSource.`Id`
               AND DataSource.`WorkflowId` = Workflow.`Id`
               AND DataSource.IsDeleted = 0) AS WrappedData
ORDER  BY WrappedData.`Timestamp` ASC
LIMIT  0, 1
```

Comment: the query would be nice.

Comment: lol! and the table defs would be handy too :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off it seems odd that this is one big subquery. Why can't you do this:

```
SELECT DataSource.Id,
               DataSourceActivityLog.Description,
               DataSourceActivityLog.UserId,
               DataSource.Status    AS StatusCode,
               ( CASE
                   WHEN User.Name IS NULL THEN 'System'
                   ELSE User.Name
                 END )              AS `Username`,
               ReadyLog.`Timestamp` AS `Received`,
               DataSourceActivityLog.`Timestamp`
        FROM   DataSource
               LEFT JOIN DataSourceActivityLog AS ReadyLog
                 ON ( ( ReadyLog.DataSourceId = DataSource.Id
                        AND ReadyLog.Description = 'ready' )
                       OR ( ReadyLog.DataSourceId = DataSource.RootId
                            AND ReadyLog.Description = 'ready' ) ),
               DataSourceActivityLog
               LEFT JOIN USER
                 ON USER.Id = DataSourceActivityLog.UserId,
               Workflow
        WHERE  DataSource.Id IN (... )
               AND DataSourceActivityLog.Id = (SELECT DataSourceActivityLog.Id
                                               FROM   DataSourceActivityLog
                                               WHERE  DataSourceActivityLog.DataSourceId = DataSource.Id
                                                      AND ( DataSourceActivityLog.Description = 'data_entry_ready' )
                                               ORDER  BY TIMESTAMP DESC
                                               LIMIT  1)
               AND ( DataSource.Status = '103' )
               AND Workflow.Id = 14
               AND DataSourceActivityLog.`DataSourceId` = DataSource.`Id`
               AND DataSource.`WorkflowId` = Workflow.`Id`
               AND DataSource.IsDeleted = 0
ORDER  BY DataSourceActivityLog.`Timestamp` ASC
LIMIT  0, 1
```

I suspect, but may be wrong, that `WrappedData` is derived that the ORDER BY is inefficient as it can't use any index and must wait for the entire query to complete before sorting.

Next, it seems some where clauses should be move into joins like this:

```
SELECT DataSource.Id,
               DataSourceActivityLog.Description,
               DataSourceActivityLog.UserId,
               DataSource.Status    AS StatusCode,
               ( CASE
                   WHEN User.Name IS NULL THEN 'System'
                   ELSE User.Name
                 END )              AS `Username`,
               ReadyLog.`Timestamp` AS `Received`,
               DataSourceActivityLog.`Timestamp`
        FROM   DataSource
               LEFT JOIN DataSourceActivityLog AS ReadyLog
                 ON ( ( ReadyLog.DataSourceId = DataSource.Id
                        AND ReadyLog.Description = 'ready' )
                       OR ( ReadyLog.DataSourceId = DataSource.RootId
                            AND ReadyLog.Description = 'ready' ) ),
               INNER JOIN DataSourceActivityLog  ON DataSourceActivityLog.`DataSourceId` = DataSource.`Id`
                                               AND DataSourceActivityLog.Id = (SELECT DataSourceActivityLog.Id
                                               FROM   DataSourceActivityLog
                                               WHERE  DataSourceActivityLog.DataSourceId = DataSource.Id
                                                      AND ( DataSourceActivityLog.Description = 'data_entry_ready' )
                                               ORDER  BY TIMESTAMP DESC
                                               LIMIT  1)
               LEFT JOIN USER
                 ON USER.Id = DataSourceActivityLog.UserId
               INNER JOIN Workflow ON DataSource.`WorkflowId` = Workflow.`Id`
        WHERE  DataSource.Id IN (... )
               AND ( DataSource.Status = '103' )
               AND Workflow.Id = 14
               AND DataSource.IsDeleted = 0
ORDER  BY DataSourceActivityLog.`Timestamp` ASC
LIMIT  0, 1
```

Also, the aliased `DataSourceActivityLog AS ReadyLog` looks like it is returning quite a few rows. Should this be an `INNER JOIN` rather than a `LEFT JOIN`? Hard to tell based on what you have provided.

Finally, the `DataSource.Id IN (... )` is so long it might benefit you to put these IDs into a lookup table that you can reference via a join rather than spilling them all out in the where clause.

I know this doesn't help you with `EXPLAIN` but honestly I don't think it is giving you much to go on in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following, first put the Id's of the `IN` clause in a temp table (TempIds); if you can be certain that a record with `Id=14` exists in table `Workflow`, then you can remove the `INNER JOIN` to `Workflow` table and leave a simple condition of `DataSource.WorkflowId = 14` in the `WHERE` clause; then change the order of the joins so that `INNER JOIN` are evaluated first, then `LEFT JOIN`; simplify the first `LEFT JOIN` expression and move the invariant condition `ReadyLog.Description = 'ready'` out of the `OR`:

```
SELECT DataSource.Id,
    DataSourceActivityLog.Description,
    DataSourceActivityLog.UserId,
    DataSource.Status    AS StatusCode,
    ( CASE
        WHEN User.Name IS NULL THEN 'System'
        ELSE User.Name
    END )              AS `Username`,
    ReadyLog.`Timestamp` AS `Received`,
    DataSourceActivityLog.`Timestamp`
FROM
    TempIds INNER JOIN
    DataSource ON TempIds.Id = DataSource.Id INNER JOIN
    DataSourceActivityLog ON DataSourceActivityLog.DataSourceId = DataSource.Id 
        AND DataSourceActivityLog.Id = (
            SELECT DataSourceActivityLog.Id
            FROM   DataSourceActivityLog
            WHERE  DataSourceActivityLog.Description = 'data_entry_ready'
                AND DataSourceActivityLog.DataSourceId = DataSource.Id
            ORDER  BY TIMESTAMP DESC
            LIMIT  1) LEFT JOIN
    DataSourceActivityLog AS ReadyLog ON ReadyLog.Description = 'ready'
        AND (ReadyLog.DataSourceId = DataSource.Id
             OR ReadyLog.DataSourceId = DataSource.RootId) LEFT JOIN
    USER ON USER.Id = DataSourceActivityLog.UserId
WHERE
    DataSource.Status = '103'
    AND DataSource.WorkflowId = 14
    AND DataSource.IsDeleted = 0
ORDER  BY DataSourceActivityLog.`Timestamp` ASC
LIMIT  0, 1;
```

Finally you should consider adding the following index to `DataSourceActivityLog` table:

```
(Description ASC, DataSourceId ASC)
```